# Delphi annotations

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I was looking at the implementation of the TCustomComboBoxEx object since I need to create a custom combo box in delphi and I was triying to get what I needed, when suddenly I came over this piece of code:

```
...
[UIPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Window=UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows)]
procedure TCustomComboBoxEx.CreateWnd;
var
  ChildHandle: THandle;
  I: Integer;
  StrEnum: IEnumString;
  EditHandle: THandle;
begin
...
```

What is that upon the procedure name? What is its purpose?

Code like that work in delphi 2007 (my code needs to keep compatibility with that version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are attributes. They were added to the standard VCL controls for support of the VCL.NET (which no longer exists, BTW). Attributes are supported now with Delphi 2010 and up.

You can read more in the Delphi documentation [wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Attributes_Index)

Comment: It was Delphi 2010 which introduced support for annotations (for Win32 platform applications)

Comment: Interesting but it doesn't seem to be something the compiler enforces? I mean like SAL works in VS (http://blogs.msdn.com/michael_howard/archive/2006/05/19/602077.aspx)

Comment: @Remko: Yeah, they aren't enforced by the compiler because if they were, then all the .NET attributes would break, and for whatever reason they don't want to go through and remove them from the VCL source.  I believe either Allen Bauer or Barry Kelly said at one point that Delphi.NET is still used and maintained internally at Embarcadero, though I can't remember where I heard that.

Comment: @Remko: Thanks for the correction. I couldn't remember if it was 2009 or 2010.