# Delphi allows undefined attributes

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have some enums that i want to tag with a specific attribute so I can process the enums usin RTTI. Like this:

```
Type
  [VbEnumAttribute]
  TFieldDataType        = (Numeric, Alphanumeric);
  [VbEnumAttribute]
  TLengthUnits          = (Characters, Bytes);
```

However, the attribute VbEnumAttribute is declared in another unit and if I forget to include this unit the program still compiles, but the attribute [VbEnumAttribute] is undefined and RTTI will not report it (i.e. the two enums above have no attributes associated with them)

Is there a way to instruct Delphi to report this as an error? I am not sure why Delphi allows undefined attributes when they are not reported by RTTI.

Comment: See the comment by Mason on the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088811/delphi-annotations) on the why part of your question.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that also implies that it is not possible to force the compiler to not allow undeclared attributes.

Comment: Most likely a true conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

Such code will, by default, produce a compiler warning:

> W1025 Unsupported language feature: 'custom attribute'

If that is not sufficient for you, you can specify in your compiler options that W1025 be treated as an error.

Comment: Thank you so much! My application is in an experimental phase right now, so I didn't catch that warning amongs the other warnings. I will turn it into an error which is absolutely the best in my case.